# How set default number (1) in the interactive custom function

Tags: read

here custom function:

```
(defun increment-number-at-point(number)
  (interactive "nInput increment number:")
  (skip-chars-backward "0-9")
  (or (looking-at "[0-9]+")
      (error "No number at point"))
  (replace-match (number-to-string (+ number (string-to-number (match-string 0))))))
```

Nice it's work fine.
But I want to set default value (1) when user not input any number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `read-number` directly:

```
(interactive (list (read-number "Input increment number: " 1)))
```